# logcat report of push not being enabled correclty

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using Parse as a back end for my app and I used their [quick start guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing) to setup push notifications.

I've followed it step by step and do not get pushes. Also I get this report in logcat when I start the app

```
08-22 18:46:34.785    4325-4325/maxbleggi.afstudentplanner D/com.parse.ParsePushChannelsController﹕ Tried to subscribe or unsubscribe from a channel, but push is not enabled correctly. Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to use GCM for push: make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported=false>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But I followed the guide and I believe my manifest is correct

here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".utils.InitializeParse"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterPart_2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_part_2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterPart2TeacherActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_part2_teacher" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterPart_3TeacherActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_part_3_teacher" >
    </activity>

    <!--<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"/>
               android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_bt"-->

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
               android:exported="false">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

     <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
               android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
             <category android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

 </application>

 </manifest>
```

here is where I start parse

```
    ...
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {

            } else
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

When I use my device I do not receive this logcat report but I do receive it when I use an emulator

Comment: Which emulator are you using? Does it have Google Apps installed ? If not, that might be the problem.

Comment: nexus 5 on genymotion. It should work on it though. The thing is I don't receive pushes on my device either

Comment: It might be helpful if you [Instal ARM translation in Genymotion](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) See [Unable to get push notification when using Genymotion as my emulator of my android app](https://www.parse.com/questions/unable-to-get-push-notification-when-using-genymotion-as-my-emulator-of-my-android-app)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and tell you what happens

Comment: Sure. Let us know if it worked or not

Comment: yep I am no longer getting that debug report anymore thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm posting the answer for future reference of anyone who might have the same issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as emulator and it does not have Google Apps installed on it, that might cause the issue. Try to [Install ARM translation](https://www.parse.com/questions/unable-to-get-push-notification-when-using-genymotion-as-my-emulator-of-my-android-app) and check again. For more see [Unable to get push notification when using Genymotion as my emulator of my android app](https://www.parse.com/questions/unable-to-get-push-notification-when-using-genymotion-as-my-emulator-of-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

I know there could be complex emulator problems but picking a simple one you seem to be missing a permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```